# How to display page title of menu / sub menu page?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to know what the usage of $page_title in function add_menu_page or add_submenu_page because I don't see it in the menu / sub menu page. 
To have the title, I have to manually code the plugin, such as :

```
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Page Title</h2>
....
```

Here is the code for creating menu / sub menu :

```
add_menu_page( 
        'Menu Page Title', 
        'Menu Title', 
        'publish_posts', 
        'otto-ext' );

add_submenu_page( 
        'otto-ext', 
        'Sub Menu Page Title', 
        'Sub Menu Title', 
        'publish_posts', 
        'location-ext', 
        'custom_menu' );
```

Is it possible to display "Menu Page Title" or "Sub Menu Page Title" automatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a menu and sub-menu using scripts:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'MyPluginMenu' );

function MyPluginMenu() {
  $SettingsPath = 'path_to_plugin/menu_script.php';
  add_menu_page( 'PageTitle', 'MenuTitle', 'administrator', $SettingsPath, '', plugins_url( 'path_to_plugin/images/plugin_icon.png' ) );
  add_submenu_page( $SettingsPath, 'PageTitle', 'SubMenuTitle', 'administrator', 'path_to_plugin/sub_menu_script.php', '' );
}
```

This will work for **PLUGINS** as you mentioned in your question `I have to manually code the plugin, such as:`.

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm two years late to the party, but for those still landing on this page:

You can use [`get_admin_page_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_admin_page_title/), which has been available since 2.5. Alternatively, you can just use `$GLOBALS['title']`, which WordPress sets as soon as **admin-header.php** is loaded.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h2><?php echo $GLOBALS['title'] ?></h2>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. You will have to code the title manually. The `$page_title` parameter is only for the title tag in the head section of the HTML document, `<title>$page_title</title>`, which is used as the "name" of the tab in your browser.

There is no way to use the parameters given to add_menu_page inside the function that echoes the content of the page you're creating. So no, there is no easy way to generate page titles automatically from that information.